# User centered top list

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array with users sorted by score.
I only want to output a specific users score (in the middle of the outputted list), and users before and after to make the list max length 10.

Like this

```
1.  A
2.  B
3.  C
--------- OUTPUT START
4.  D
5.  E
6.  F
7.  G
8.  H (ME)
9.  I
10. J
11. K
12. L
13. M
--------- OUTPUT END
14. N
15. O
16. P
```

Any ideas on how to do this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that:

```
$my_rank;
foreach ($scores as $key => $value) {
  if ($value == 'H') { // 'H' being your name.
    $my_rank = $key;
  }
}
$surroundings = array_slice($scores, max(0, $my_rank - 4), 10);
```

It takes the id of your name in the array and slices the array from your rank-4 with size of 10. If your rank is less than 4, it takes 0 instead (it's the `max` part).

Answer (score 0):

See [array_slice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

```
$new_list = array_slice($array, 3, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you've got an array of user ids like this : `$arr = [0]->7364,[1]->8742,[2]->9483...`
you can generate new array by:

```
$sibling_array = []; //new array
$myId //this user id
$myPos = array_search($myId, $arr); //position of this user

if ($myPos > 10) { // middle of list
$sibling_array = array_slice($arr, $myPos-10, $myPos+10);
} else { //close to top
$sibling_array = array_slice($arr, 0, $myPos+10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$start_index =array_search("D",$your_array);
for($i=$start_index; $i<count(your_array) && $i<10; $i++)
       echo($your_array[$i])
```